# How to enumerate the available KMS modes using the open syscall and KMS file descriptor?

Tags: linux-kernel, gpu, screen-resolution, drm, libvirt

I am trying to install a vGPU platform on Ubuntu 20.04, but the host resolution seems locked. Xrandr didn't work and returned "Failed to get size of gamma".
I received an instruction that says, "You can enumerate the available KMS modes if you read from the KMS file descriptor using the open syscall. Using that you can control the GPU. drmModeGetResources(drm_fd) will return a struct with several unint32 items including framebuffers, crtcs, connectors, encoders, resolutions, etc…"

Here are my attempts and the results:

Attempt 1: I'm not sure how to "read from the KMS file descriptor using the open syscall". I tried to install "drmModeGetResources" through 'apt install', but it returns "unable to locate package drmModeGetResources".

Attempt 2: I tried "fbset" with the following command, which executed successfully but didn't change the resolution:

```
sudo fbset - -geometry 1920 1080 1920 1080 32
```

Attempt 3: I ran "drmModeGetResources(drm_fd)" in the terminal and got this error: "syntax error near unexpected token drm_fd".

Can someone explain what this instruction means and how to follow it?

Comment: Hi! I think I’ve found some solutions here: https://github.com/Arc-Compute/IOVInfo